# Optimizing a foreach with an embeded lapply loop - Is it possible to optimize code?

Tags: r, foreach, time-series, lapply, doparallel

I have the below chunk of code that is running properly but is too time & resource consuming. Especially, when I run it for the full dataset. I was wondering if there is anyway to optimize it and decrease the required processing resources and time keeping the *overlap* and *window_size* values the same.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cores=parallel::detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores-1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

overlap <- 32
window_size <- 512

start_pos <- seq(1, 20480, by = overlap)

lst_B2_512_32 <- list()

##Edit: changed the fixed 2156 length of the loop to length(unique(test_1st_binded_B2$ID)
lst_B2_512_32 <- foreach(i=1:length(unique(test_1st_binded_B2$ID)), .verbose = T) %dopar% {
  lst_B2_512_32[[i]] <- lapply(start_pos, function(x) test_1st_binded_B2[test_1st_binded_B2$ID==i,][(c(x:(x + window_size-1))),])
}
```

Here is the result of 'dput(head(test_1st_binded_B2))'

```
structure(list(B2_X = c(-0.183, -0.164, -0.195, -0.159, -0.261, 
-0.281), B2_Y = c(-0.054, -0.183, -0.125, -0.178, -0.098, -0.125
), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Edit - Instead of using the dput reults, this  snippet of code helps reproduce the "test_1st_binded_B2" data.frame and easily scale it by changing the value of n.

```
n <- 2
B2x <- rnorm(20480*n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
B2y <- rnorm(20480*n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
id <- 1:n

test_1st_binded_B2 <- data.frame(B2_X = B2x, B2_Y = B2y, ID = id)
```

The original test_1st_binded_B2 is a total of 44154880 observations comprised of 20480 observations for each of the 2156 IDs. It is a part of a bearing run to failure simulation data.

Comment: I tried to run the example but it did not work. Are you able to create a MRE that  generates data and is scalable?

Comment: I amended the question and added a snippet of code that hopefully answers your request. Please let me know if you have further questions/requests.

Comment: I am not really familiar with `foreach` and `doParallel`, and I am not sure why you would like to do this. This indeed is very inefficient. Are you trying to implement a sliding window, or are you just trying to chop the `data.frame` into a `list` of N observations per item? If you don't need a sliding window, then you can use `dplyr::group_by` and`dplyr::group_split` instead. If you do, then it will be harder.

Comment: Hi Van - I need the overlapping sliding window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that may help. Both of which I would recommend staying away from `foreach` for now unless there is a more concrete use case.

```r
library (data.table)
dt = as.data.table(test_1st_binded_B2)
dt[, .(lapply(start_pos, function(i) .SD[i:(i + window_size - 1L)])), by = ID]
```

Using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package, we can make use of high performing grouping. In the original example, each grouping was subsetted. That is, anytime we have a grouping problem `DF[ grp == this_grp, ]` means that we have to keep comparing the grouping column. Instead, grouping allows us to more efficiently split and apply our functions.

Going further, `lapply(starts, function(i) DF[i:(i + window_size - 1), ]` can  be somewhat inefficient because we build up a larger dataframe or list. We could instead directly subset the grouped data.

```
dt[, .SD[sequence(rep.int(window_size, length(start_pos)), start_pos)
         ][, list(list(.SD)), by = gl(length(start_pos), window_size)]
         , by = ID]
```

System timings are:

OP - 1.59 seconds

First option - 0.32 seconds

Second Option - 0.08 seconds

Comment: Thank you Cole. It seems to be working really quick (minutes compared to hours)! I am waiting for administrator to update R to run a complete test. The current R3.5.x has the sequence function not accepting the "from" argument. Wait for another update.

Comment: Ok @Cole. This is brilliant. The code runs just fine and it finishes the job in 2-3 mins on a single core. However it is still eating up memory. Thank you so much, this was really helpful!

Comment: Great! As for the memory, I was following the example. It’ll as long as you need to return a list of the window, it will be memory intense. It would be better to do some sort of function and return a value like a rolling mean or sum.