# 2 consecutive nested for-loops - Is it possible to optimize with data.table or apply? Added data.table attempt yet to be optimized

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, mapply

I have a data.table made of data.tables as per the dput at the end of this question. I manipulate this data.table of data.tables using the following nested for-loops:

```
test_E2 <- list()
for (i in unique(lst_512_32_E2$ID)){
     test_E2[[i]] <- list()
     for (j in 1:length(lst_512_32_E2$V1[[i]])){
          test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i]$V1, '[[', j)
     }
}

t_test_E2 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(test_E2)){
     t_test_E2[[i]] <- list()
     for (j in 1:length(test_E2[[i]])){
          t_test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- t(test_E2[[i]][[j]])
     }
}
```

Any chance these for-loops could be re-generated/optimized while staying in the data.table world? What about an apply/mapply function as a second alternative? Minding that I want the final output as matrix.

Edit 1 (revised code):

```
#This function will be used to delete null list elements
delete.NULLs  <-  function(x.list){
     x.list[unlist(lapply(x.list, length) != 0)]
}

#I revised the nested loop to accommodate more than one variable, i.e., V1, V2, V3, etc.
test_E2 <- list()
for (i in unique(lst_512_32_E2$ID)){
     test_E2[[i]] <- list()
     for (j in 2:length(lst_512_32_E2)){
          test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- (sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i,..j][[1]], '[[',1))
     }
}

#This is where the NULL list elements are deleted.
test_E2 <- lapply(test_E2, delete.NULLs)

#This is the same. Could be eliminated using Karl's answer though
t_test_E2 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(test_E2)){
     t_test_E2[[i]] <- list()
     for (j in 1:length(test_E2[[i]])){
          t_test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- t(test_E2[[i]][[j]])
     }
}
```

I refer you to this question which was of help before. Maybe it brings up some ideas: [Optimizing a foreach with an embeded lapply loop - Is it possible to optimize code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830782/optimizing-a-foreach-with-an-embeded-lapply-loop-is-it-possible-to-optimize-co)

Edit 2: Trying to play with data.table syntax

```
#Test_E22 and Test_E222 could be chained but they're kept separate for readability.
test_E22 <- lst_512_32_E2[,.(.(lapply(.SD, function(x) .(sapply(x, '[[',1))))),by = ID]
test_E222 <- test_E22[,.(lapply(.SD, function(x) matrix(unlist(x),nrow = window_size))), by=ID]

#Turning the data.table into a list of data.tables
abc <- lapply(unique(test_E222$ID), function(x) test_E222[ID==x][,c(.SD), by=ID])

#Combine Values into a Vector or List. Can the V1 inside the c() be replaced with a function and still return a vector or list? What if if I want to return more than one vector or list in the case I have V1, V2, etc.?
abc2 <- lapply(abc, function(x) x[,c(V1)])

#This is a first attempt at it to keep the community engaged with the question. Hopefully, someone is able to optimize it further and can help resolve the c() issue.
```

Edit 3: What is the code supposed to achieve?
I have been asked couple of times what is the code supposed to achieve. Will try to answer by going through the loops of the first nested loop bottom up:

```
sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i,..j][[1]], '[[',1))
```

For each sliding window within ID==i of variable j (only V1 of interest here), 625 windows in this sapply, return the sliding window time series (512 readings) of that sliding window.

```
for (j in 2:length(lst_512_32_E2))
```

Apply the sapply for the variables of interest (only V1 of interest here) skipping the ID column.

```
for (i in unique(lst_512_32_E2$ID))
```

Repeat this for each decomposed time signal.

The second nested loop is basically transposing the output to have each time increment (t1, t2,... and tn) from each sliding window of in one vector. To generate the results, please run the 2 nested loops on the dput below.

dput:

```
print(dput(lst_512_32_E2[1:2]))
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L), gl = structure(1:2, levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", 
"281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", 
"299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", 
"308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", 
"317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", 
"335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", 
"344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", 
"362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", 
"371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", 
"380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", 
"389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", 
"398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", 
"407", "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", 
"416", "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", 
"425", "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", 
"434", "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", 
"443", "444", "445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "451", 
"452", "453", "454", "455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", 
"461", "462", "463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", 
"470", "471", "472", "473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "478", 
"479", "480", "481", "482", "483", "484", "485", "486", "487", 
"488", "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", 
"497", "498", "499", "500", "501", "502", "503", "504", "505", 
"506", "507", "508", "509", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514", 
"515", "516", "517", "518", "519", "520", "521", "522", "523", 
"524", "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", 
"533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540", "541", 
"542", "543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550", 
"551", "552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", "558", "559", 
"560", "561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", "567", "568", 
"569", "570", "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", "576", "577", 
"578", "579", "580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "585", "586", 
"587", "588", "589", "590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "595", 
"596", "597", "598", "599", "600", "601", "602", "603", "604", 
"605", "606", "607", "608", "609", "610", "611", "612", "613", 
"614", "615", "616", "617", "618", "619", "620", "621", "622", 
"623", "624", "625", "626", "627", "628", "629", "630", "631", 
"632", "633", "634", "635", "636", "637", "638", "639", "640"
), class = "factor"), V1 = list(structure(list(V1 = c(-0.049, 
-0.042, 0.015, -0.051, -0.107, -0.078, -0.02, -0.046, -0.063, 
0.068, 0.095, -0.007, -0.046, 0.044, 0.137, 0.098, 0.081, -0.073, 
-0.037, 0.012, -0.037, -0.044, 0.015, 0.044, -0.029, -0.09, -0.061, 
-0.042, -0.002, 0.007, 0.024, -0.005, -0.11, -0.076, 0.032, 0.088, 
-0.005, -0.105, -0.117, -0.071, -0.002, -0.017, -0.034, -0.098, 
-0.071, -0.056, -0.083, -0.093, -0.012, 0.002, 0.042, -0.056, 
-0.017, 0.007, -0.015, 0.02, 0.015, 0.007, 0.029, 0.054, 0.01, 
-0.007, -0.056, -0.049, -0.034, 0.002, 0.017, -0.071, -0.103, 
-0.093, -0.051, -0.01, -0.107, -0.063, 0.054, 0.007, 0.037, 0.071, 
0.107, -0.02, -0.056, -0.078, 0.027, 0.063, -0.051, -0.115, -0.068, 
-0.059, -0.024, -0.044, 0.027, -0.012, -0.054, -0.02, 0.022, 
-0.066, -0.037, 0.117, 0.071, 0.029, 0.015, -0.032, 0.027, -0.044, 
-0.22, -0.2, -0.024, 0.007, -0.129, -0.068, 0.044, 0.059, 0.012, 
0.002, -0.068, 0.029, 0.117, 0.039, 0.005, 0.088, 0.032, -0.095, 
-0.076, -0.032, -0.059, -0.142, -0.164, -0.071, -0.02, -0.032, 
-0.088, -0.022, 0.032, 0.032, 0.007, -0.022, -0.042, 0.024, 0.042, 
-0.017, -0.034, 0.01, 0.002, -0.076, -0.078, -0.054, -0.095, 
-0.073, -0.034, -0.103, -0.081, -0.088, -0.017, -0.049, 0.012, 
-0.09, -0.122, 0.01, 0.022, 0.122, 0.107, 0.012, -0.017, -0.107, 
-0.107, 0.034, -0.034, -0.044, -0.061, -0.115, -0.132, -0.193, 
-0.029, 0.078, 0.093, 0.1, 0.049, -0.037, 0.029, -0.027, 0.002, 
0.081, -0.024, -0.083, -0.046, -0.002, -0.037, -0.149, -0.02, 
0.01, -0.049, -0.105, -0.051, 0.078, 0.071, 0.007, -0.081, 0.054, 
0.164, 0.042, 0.073, -0.02, -0.032, 0.015, 0.002, -0.081, 0.042, 
0.024, -0.132, -0.063, 0.051, 0.02, 0, 0.02, -0.01, -0.005, 0.071, 
0.01, -0.005, 0.088, 0.037, -0.015, -0.042, -0.024, -0.012, 0.071, 
-0.022, -0.1, -0.115, -0.029, -0.01, -0.002, -0.051, -0.081, 
0.027, 0.11, 0.022, -0.061, 0.061, 0.01, -0.012, -0.02, -0.049, 
0.029, 0.01, -0.029, -0.032, 0.01, 0.042, -0.01, 0.042, 0.034, 
-0.088, -0.083, -0.09, 0.037, -0.002, 0.056, 0.024, 0.044, 0.154, 
0.088, 0.027, 0.034, 0.105, 0.081, -0.02, -0.083, -0.068, -0.017, 
0.034, 0.042, -0.073, -0.112, -0.015, 0.088, 0.071, -0.066, -0.085, 
0.083, 0.156, 0.105, -0.073, -0.071, 0.09, 0.078, -0.051, -0.142, 
-0.076, 0.005, -0.01, -0.093, -0.076, -0.049, 0.056, 0.01, -0.046, 
0.042, 0.132, 0.049, -0.029, 0.044, 0.107, 0.122, 0.068, -0.002, 
-0.078, -0.012, -0.037, -0.105, -0.115, 0.017, 0.042, 0.015, 
0.032, 0.054, 0.024, -0.002, 0.083, 0.061, -0.007, 0.056, 0.046, 
-0.01, 0.049, 0.022, -0.024, -0.024, -0.022, -0.127, -0.176, 
-0.081, -0.068, 0, 0.015, -0.029, -0.017, -0.027, -0.002, 0.054, 
0.005, -0.022, -0.027, -0.007, 0.095, 0.029, -0.085, -0.059, 
-0.063, 0.024, 0.029, -0.063, -0.078, -0.127, -0.068, -0.022, 
-0.029, 0.046, 0.029, 0.01, 0.039, 0.132, 0.068, 0.044, 0.012, 
-0.029, -0.015, 0.093, -0.01, -0.134, -0.115, -0.066, -0.032, 
0.002, -0.039, -0.134, -0.051, 0.034, 0.061, 0.066, 0.061, 0.066, 
0.01, 0.024, 0.093, 0.044, 0.037, 0.012, 0.002, -0.027, -0.11, 
-0.11, -0.073, -0.029, 0.032, 0.005, -0.066, -0.005, -0.02, -0.029, 
-0.068, -0.01, 0.071, 0.081, 0.034, -0.037, -0.032, -0.007, -0.012, 
-0.073, -0.088, -0.071, -0.049, -0.083, -0.044, -0.112, 0.015, 
-0.1, -0.154, 0.029, 0.073, 0.073, 0, -0.01, 0.005, -0.012, -0.103, 
-0.12, -0.093, -0.042, -0.024, -0.154, -0.073, -0.054, -0.1, 
-0.125, -0.117, -0.066, 0.034, 0.085, 0.012, 0.039, 0.085, 0.005, 
-0.022, -0.017, 0.02, 0.039, -0.046, -0.007, 0.012, -0.012, -0.063, 
-0.054, 0.007, -0.056, -0.107, 0.037, 0.093, 0.046, -0.061, -0.015, 
0.039, 0.024, 0.068, 0.007, -0.027, 0.051, -0.134, -0.11, 0.007, 
-0.093, -0.105, -0.056, -0.076, 0.012, -0.071, -0.056, -0.117, 
-0.073, 0.002, 0.054, 0.078, 0.09, 0.11, 0.09, -0.022, -0.044, 
0.042, 0.073, -0.005, 0.015, 0.017, -0.085, -0.1, -0.085, -0.059, 
-0.103, -0.071, -0.056, -0.034, 0.032, 0.039, -0.007, -0.007, 
0.068, 0.027, -0.054, -0.078, -0.061, -0.059, -0.024)), row.names = c(NA, 
-512L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    V1 = c(-0.11, -0.076, 0.032, 0.088, -0.005, -0.105, -0.117, 
    -0.071, -0.002, -0.017, -0.034, -0.098, -0.071, -0.056, -0.083, 
    -0.093, -0.012, 0.002, 0.042, -0.056, -0.017, 0.007, -0.015, 
    0.02, 0.015, 0.007, 0.029, 0.054, 0.01, -0.007, -0.056, -0.049, 
    -0.034, 0.002, 0.017, -0.071, -0.103, -0.093, -0.051, -0.01, 
    -0.107, -0.063, 0.054, 0.007, 0.037, 0.071, 0.107, -0.02, 
    -0.056, -0.078, 0.027, 0.063, -0.051, -0.115, -0.068, -0.059, 
    -0.024, -0.044, 0.027, -0.012, -0.054, -0.02, 0.022, -0.066, 
    -0.037, 0.117, 0.071, 0.029, 0.015, -0.032, 0.027, -0.044, 
    -0.22, -0.2, -0.024, 0.007, -0.129, -0.068, 0.044, 0.059, 
    0.012, 0.002, -0.068, 0.029, 0.117, 0.039, 0.005, 0.088, 
    0.032, -0.095, -0.076, -0.032, -0.059, -0.142, -0.164, -0.071, 
    -0.02, -0.032, -0.088, -0.022, 0.032, 0.032, 0.007, -0.022, 
    -0.042, 0.024, 0.042, -0.017, -0.034, 0.01, 0.002, -0.076, 
    -0.078, -0.054, -0.095, -0.073, -0.034, -0.103, -0.081, -0.088, 
    -0.017, -0.049, 0.012, -0.09, -0.122, 0.01, 0.022, 0.122, 
    0.107, 0.012, -0.017, -0.107, -0.107, 0.034, -0.034, -0.044, 
    -0.061, -0.115, -0.132, -0.193, -0.029, 0.078, 0.093, 0.1, 
    0.049, -0.037, 0.029, -0.027, 0.002, 0.081, -0.024, -0.083, 
    -0.046, -0.002, -0.037, -0.149, -0.02, 0.01, -0.049, -0.105, 
    -0.051, 0.078, 0.071, 0.007, -0.081, 0.054, 0.164, 0.042, 
    0.073, -0.02, -0.032, 0.015, 0.002, -0.081, 0.042, 0.024, 
    -0.132, -0.063, 0.051, 0.02, 0, 0.02, -0.01, -0.005, 0.071, 
    0.01, -0.005, 0.088, 0.037, -0.015, -0.042, -0.024, -0.012, 
    0.071, -0.022, -0.1, -0.115, -0.029, -0.01, -0.002, -0.051, 
    -0.081, 0.027, 0.11, 0.022, -0.061, 0.061, 0.01, -0.012, 
    -0.02, -0.049, 0.029, 0.01, -0.029, -0.032, 0.01, 0.042, 
    -0.01, 0.042, 0.034, -0.088, -0.083, -0.09, 0.037, -0.002, 
    0.056, 0.024, 0.044, 0.154, 0.088, 0.027, 0.034, 0.105, 0.081, 
    -0.02, -0.083, -0.068, -0.017, 0.034, 0.042, -0.073, -0.112, 
    -0.015, 0.088, 0.071, -0.066, -0.085, 0.083, 0.156, 0.105, 
    -0.073, -0.071, 0.09, 0.078, -0.051, -0.142, -0.076, 0.005, 
    -0.01, -0.093, -0.076, -0.049, 0.056, 0.01, -0.046, 0.042, 
    0.132, 0.049, -0.029, 0.044, 0.107, 0.122, 0.068, -0.002, 
    -0.078, -0.012, -0.037, -0.105, -0.115, 0.017, 0.042, 0.015, 
    0.032, 0.054, 0.024, -0.002, 0.083, 0.061, -0.007, 0.056, 
    0.046, -0.01, 0.049, 0.022, -0.024, -0.024, -0.022, -0.127, 
    -0.176, -0.081, -0.068, 0, 0.015, -0.029, -0.017, -0.027, 
    -0.002, 0.054, 0.005, -0.022, -0.027, -0.007, 0.095, 0.029, 
    -0.085, -0.059, -0.063, 0.024, 0.029, -0.063, -0.078, -0.127, 
    -0.068, -0.022, -0.029, 0.046, 0.029, 0.01, 0.039, 0.132, 
    0.068, 0.044, 0.012, -0.029, -0.015, 0.093, -0.01, -0.134, 
    -0.115, -0.066, -0.032, 0.002, -0.039, -0.134, -0.051, 0.034, 
    0.061, 0.066, 0.061, 0.066, 0.01, 0.024, 0.093, 0.044, 0.037, 
    0.012, 0.002, -0.027, -0.11, -0.11, -0.073, -0.029, 0.032, 
    0.005, -0.066, -0.005, -0.02, -0.029, -0.068, -0.01, 0.071, 
    0.081, 0.034, -0.037, -0.032, -0.007, -0.012, -0.073, -0.088, 
    -0.071, -0.049, -0.083, -0.044, -0.112, 0.015, -0.1, -0.154, 
    0.029, 0.073, 0.073, 0, -0.01, 0.005, -0.012, -0.103, -0.12, 
    -0.093, -0.042, -0.024, -0.154, -0.073, -0.054, -0.1, -0.125, 
    -0.117, -0.066, 0.034, 0.085, 0.012, 0.039, 0.085, 0.005, 
    -0.022, -0.017, 0.02, 0.039, -0.046, -0.007, 0.012, -0.012, 
    -0.063, -0.054, 0.007, -0.056, -0.107, 0.037, 0.093, 0.046, 
    -0.061, -0.015, 0.039, 0.024, 0.068, 0.007, -0.027, 0.051, 
    -0.134, -0.11, 0.007, -0.093, -0.105, -0.056, -0.076, 0.012, 
    -0.071, -0.056, -0.117, -0.073, 0.002, 0.054, 0.078, 0.09, 
    0.11, 0.09, -0.022, -0.044, 0.042, 0.073, -0.005, 0.015, 
    0.017, -0.085, -0.1, -0.085, -0.059, -0.103, -0.071, -0.056, 
    -0.034, 0.032, 0.039, -0.007, -0.007, 0.068, 0.027, -0.054, 
    -0.078, -0.061, -0.059, -0.024, 0.037, -0.007, -0.083, -0.032, 
    -0.061, -0.081, -0.093, -0.117, 0.034, 0.044, 0.037, 0.054, 
    0.083, 0.002, -0.103, 0.083, 0.115, -0.139, -0.046, 0.142, 
    0.032, -0.139, -0.151, 0.081, 0.107, -0.061, -0.076, 0.005, 
    0.176, 0.078, -0.061, 0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -512L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002289534be80>)
   ID gl                  V1
1:  1  1 <data.table[512x1]>
2:  1  2 <data.table[512x1]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the clarifications! It's much more clear now how to optimize.

## Assumptions

- test_E2 and t_test_E2 are each a list of lists
- test_E2 gathers results by ID, since the data for a particular ID may be dispersed throughout the data.table
- t_test_E2 transposes each element of test_E2

## Optimization

1. Instead of having two sets of nested loops, combine the processing into a single nested loop. In other words, do the transposition of each element as it is generated in test_E2 by changing

`test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i]$V1, '[[', j)`

to

`test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- t( sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i]$V1, '[[', j) )`

2. Since `sapply` is already optimized, the way to gain the most in performance will be to write a C++ function that performs `test_E2[[i]][[j]] <- t( sapply(lst_512_32_E2[ID==i]$V1, '[[', j) )`
3. Another way to speed things up would be to use parallel processing, i.e., using multiple processors.

I hope this helps!

## ------------------

### Data.Table Syntax

The article, https://www.infoworld.com/article/3575086/the-ultimate-r-datatable-cheat-sheet.html, Shows **Data.Table Code** and the equivalent **Tidyverse Code** (where applicable) for a variety of data wrangling and summarization tasks.

Of particular interest for your situation:

###### Alter data.table in place without making a copy

any function that starts with set such as setkey(mydt, mycol) or using the := operator within brackets

###### Count number of rows by groups

mydt2 <- mydt[,.N, by = groupcol] #for one group
< OR >

mydt2 <- mydt[, .N, by = .(groupcol1, groupcol2)]

###### Summarize multiple columns and return results in multiple columns

mydt2 <- mydt[, lapply(.SD, myfun), .SDcols = c("colA", "colB")]

###### Summarize multiple columns by group and return results in multiple columns

mydt2 <- mydt[, lapply(.SD, myfun), .SDcols = c("colA", "colB"), by = groupcol]

Comment: I will try to answer your queries on a series of comments and an edit to my question as appropriate.

Comment: Line 4 in the first loop is not a typo. It works fine with me. Try to initiate the Y[[ i ]] list first using line 2. Also, make sure X is a data.table not a data.frame.

Comment: As for the second question related to line 4 and what is the j doing here. J will be very useful if we have 2 or more variables in X that are overlapping sliding windows data tables, similar to V1 in X. For the example in the current question, we only have V1, hence J will loop over 1 variable only.  In the example provided with the question J=1:1.

Comment: For the third part of your answer: `# We can get V1 for X where ID == i with the following:...` Please let me know if there is something I need to clarify/answer here. I hope by these comments I provided you with more clarity on what the code is trying to accomplish. Please shout out if not and I will try to do another round of elaboration. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Karl for your edited response. Combining the two sets of nested loops into one works and is brilliant! However, I am still wondering if there is data.table syntax that could achieve the same without these too many loops. 

As for your original answer, you were right to point out a typo in the first set of nested loops (line 4). Please check the editied question for edited code.

Comment: Thanks, Karl! The data.table addition in your answer is quiet preliminary but made me doubt perhaps I am missing something from the basics. I gave it another shot with data.table syntax this time. You will find the attempt in a new edit to my question (and perhaps an answer to decrease the confusion and jargon? I am close but it still needs to be optimized by taking out the lapply(s) and being able to combine Values into a Vector or List without having to call the column name explicitly as the edit will show.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `split` + `lapply` to generate lists `test_E2`, and perform `t` over entries in `test_E2` in turn

```
test_E2 <- with(
  lst_512_32_E2,
  lapply(
    split(V1, ID),
    function(x) unname(as.matrix(do.call(cbind, x)))
  )
)

t_test_E2 <- lapply(test_E2, t)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this neglects the j loop in my nested for loops. It is also slower than the nested loops.